# About list sorting and delegates & lambda expressions Func stuff

Tags: c#

```
List<bool> test = new List<bool>();
test.Sort(new Func<bool, bool, int>((b1, b2) => 1));
```

What Am I missing?

> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Func' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer'
>
> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Sort(System.Collections.Generic.IComparer)' has some invalid arguments

When I have

```
private int func(bool b1, bool b2)
{
    return 1;
}

private void something()
{
    List<bool> test = new List<bool>();
    test.Sort(func);
}
```

it works fine. Are they not the same thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Func is the wrong delegate type. You can use either of these:

```
test.Sort((b1, b2) => 1);
test.Sort(new Comparison<bool>((b1, b2) => 1));
```

Comment: This is a good example of the compiler being smarter than you (or us, as I would have needed to look this up).  Just let it figure it out (through implicit typing in lambdas) rather than trying to explicitly tell it things it should already know.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to pass it a `System.Comparison<T>`, not a `Func<something>`. Drop the `new Func...` and it should work.

```
test.Sort((b1, b2) => !b1 && b2 ? -1 : b1 && !b2 ? +1 : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try:

```
test.Sort( delegate(bool b1,bool b2){return 1;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `new Func<...>`

```
var test = new List<bool>();
test.Sort((a, b) => 1);
```

Comment: Just my coding style.  Its equivalent to `List<bool> test = new List<bool>();`

Comment: I mean is it better to use var test = new List<bool> instead of List<bool> test = new List<bool>();

Comment: Its stylistic.  They produce exactly the same IL.